# 'unrecognized rule' and 'fatal parse error' on FLEX

Tags: python, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

i have to make a parser for a simplified Python 3 using flex and bison and im getting these 2 errors.terminal says they are on the 79th line out of the 78 i've written. i have other '.l' examples from class with this sort of format and they work fine

this is what i've written

```
    %option noyywrap

%{ 
#define YYSTYPE double
#include "scanner.tab.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

extern int flag;
extern int line;
%}

DELIMITER    [ ]+|[/t]+

KEYWORD      False|class|finally|is|return|None|continue|for|lambda|try|True|def|from|nonlocal|while|and|del|global|not|with|as|elif|if|or|yield|assert|else|import|pass|break|except|in|raise

OPERATOR     ([+\-$@&|^~])|(\*{1,2})|(\/{1,2})|(<[=<]?)|(>[=>]?)|(==)|!

COMMENT      #.+

IDENTIFIER   [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
ID_ERR       [0-9]{IDENTIFIER}

STRINGESCAPESEQ  [\\].  
SHORTSTRINGCHAR1 [^\\'\n]*
SHORTSTRINGCHAR2 [^\\"\n]*
SHORTSTRINGITEM1 {SHORTSTRINGCHAR1}|{STRINGESCAPESEQ}
SHORTSTRINGITEM2 {SHORTSTRINGCHAR2}|{STRINGESCAPESEQ}
STRING       [']{SHORTSTRINGITEM1}*[']|(["]{SHORTSTRINGITEM2}*["])
STRING_ERR   ['].[^'\n\t]*|["].[^"\n\t]* 

BINDIGIT     [01]
BININTEGER   0[bB]{BINDIGIT}+
BIN_ERR1     0[Bb]+{BINDIGIT}+

DIGIT        [0-9]
NONZERODIGIT     [1-9]
INTEGER      {NONZERODIGIT}{DIGIT}*|[0]+
INT_ERR1     {INTEGER}[a-zA-Z]{DIGIT}
INT_ERR2     [-+]{INTEGER}
INT_ERR3     [0+]{INTEGER}

INTPART      {DIGIT}+
EXPONENT     [eE][+-]*{INTPART}
FRACTION     [\.]{INTPART}
EXPONENTFLOAT    ({INTPART}|{POINTFLOAT}){EXPONENT}
POINTFLOAT   {INTPART}*{FRACTION}|{INTPART}[\.]
FLOATNUMBER  {POINTFLOAT}|{EXPONENTFLOAT}
FLOAT_ERR_POINT  {INTPART}*[\.]+{DIGIT}+[\.]*{DIGIT}*|{INTPART}[\.]+
FLOAT_ERR_SIGN   ([-+]{FLOATNUMBER})
FLOAT_ERR_LETTER {FLOATNUMBER}[A-Za-z]+

IMAGINARYNUMBER  ({FLOATNUMBER}|{INTPART})[jJ]

%%

{DELIMITER}     { }
{KEYWORD}       { return KEYWORD; }
{OPERATOR}      { }
{COMMENT}       { printf("Line %d: Found COMMENT\n", line); }   
{IDENTIFIER}        { printf("Line %d: Found IDENTIFIER %s\n", line, yytext);                    return IDENTIFIER; }
{ID_ERR}        { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong IDENTIFIER statement %s\n", line, yytext);           return ID_ERR;}  
{STRING}        { printf("Line %d: Found STRING %s\n", line, yytext);                        return STRING; }
{STRING_ERR}        { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong STRING statement %s\n", line, yytext);           return STRING_ERR;}
{BININTEGER}        { printf("Line %d: Found BINARY INTEGER NUMBER %s\n", line, yytext);                 return BININTEGER; }
{BIN_ERR1}      { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong BINARY NUMBER statement, too many 'Bb's%s\n", line, yytext); return BIN_ERR1;}
{INTEGER}       { printf("Line %d: Found INTEGER NUMBER %s\n", line, yytext);                    return INTEGER; }
{INT_ERR1}      { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong INT statement %s\n", line, yytext);              return INT_ERR1;}
{INT_ERR2}      { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong INT statement, '+/-' found %s\n", line, yytext);         return INT_ERR2;}
{INT_ERR3}      { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong INT statement, first digit(s) zeros %s\n", line, yytext);    return INT_ERR3;}
{FLOATNUMBER}       { printf("Line %d: Found FLOAT NUMBER %s\n", line, yytext);                  return FLOATNUMBER; }
{FLOAT_ERR_POINT}   { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong FLOAT statement, too many '.' %s\n", line, yytext);      return FLOAT_ERR_POINT;}
{FLOAT_ERR_POINT}   { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong FLOAT statement, '+/-' FOUND %s\n", line, yytext);       return FLOAT_ERR_SIGN;}
{FLOAT_ERR_LETTER   { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong FLOAT statement, letter FOUND %s\n", line, yytext);      return FLOAT_ERR_LETTER;}
{IMAGINARYNUMBER}   { printf("Line %d: Found IMAGINARY NUMBER %s\n", line, yytext);                  return IMAGINARYNUMBER; }
.           { printf("Line %d: UNKNOWN TOKEN:%s", line, yytext);    BEGIN(error);}
\n                  { line++; }
<<EOF>>         { printf("#END OF FILE\n"); exit(0); }
```

the full error output :

```
 flex scanner.l
 scanner.l:79: unrecognized rule
 scanner.l:79: fatal parse error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing brace at the end in line 74:

```
{FLOAT_ERR_LETTER   { printf("Line %d: !!ERROR!!\tWrong FLOAT statement, letter FOUND %s\n", line, yytext);      return FLOAT_ERR_LETTER;}
                 ^  <--- here
```

---

In a vague attempt to make this answer useful to future readers, since the problem is a simple typo, here is how I discovered the problem:

```
for n in {57..79}; do head -n$n g.l | flex -o /dev/null -w || { echo $n; break; } done
```

Most of the time a fatal error at the line after the end of the flex input is the result of a missing brace or other similar problem, but proofreading the whole file is a pain and surprisingly few IDEs correctly syntax-colour flex files. So tricks like the above can be a huge time-saver. (It's not always quite that simple; in this case, no action spanned more than one line.)

---

Once you fix that error, you will discover that several patterns cannot be matched. Line 73 can't be matched because the pattern is identical to Line 72 (`{FLOAT_ERR_POINT}`). Lines 65 and 66 (`BININTEGER` and `BIN_ERR1`) cannot be matched because the pattern in question, which starts `0B` followed by a number, also matches `IDERR`, which is (curiously) a single digit followed by an indentifier. (You probably meant `[[:digit:]]+{IDENTIFIER}`.) On the whole, you should put error patterns at the end so that they never take precedence over patterns for correct tokens. That also makes it a lot simpler to write the error tokens. (Also, you need to put specific error patterns before more general one, so that `BIN_ERR1` should come before `IDERR`.)

Some other comments:

If you want to watch flex match patterns, add `--debug` (or `-d`) to the command line, rather than sprinkling `printf` commands throughout your code. It does a better job of showing you what is happening, and can be turned on and off without editing your entire file.

<opinion>
On the whole, excessive use of flex macros as in your input file is not very useful. It actually makes the specification harder to read, since you have to look up every use of a macro. Personally, I only use macros when I need to use them several times and even then not if they are simply a way of hiding a built-in character class such as `[[:digit:]]`.
</opinion>